# Solution to a Second Order PDE

Tags: calculus, analysis, partial-differential-equations

The following PDE came up while working on a problem.

$$ f_{xx}f_{yy} - f_{xy}^2=-1 $$
$$f(x,0) = 0$$
$$f_y(x,0)= \frac{1}{x}$$

Separation of variables did not work and I am still looking for at least one solution to the PDE. The variable $x$ is taken to be greater than $1$, and the variable $y$ is taken to be nonnegative.

Comment: Hopefully you recognise this as essentially $\text{det} H = -1$, where $H$ is the [Hessian matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix). This equation is essentially the [Monge-Ampere equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monge%E2%80%93Amp%C3%A8re_equation). You can search online for articles discussing the problem, though the inhomogeneity implying the Hessian is negative definite might make things difficult.

Comment: Thank you for the note. I was aware that it was a Monge-Ampere PDE when asking the question and that the PDE is usually very difficult to solve. I wanted to state it the way I did to not scare people off when they see a determinant and a Hessian :)